# How can I render rays bounced only by certain objects?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, shadowcatcher

I need to composite some CG elements into IRL footage but blender's (frankly terrible) shadowcatcher doesn't catch reflections. Every workaround fails when rebuilding a scene because the non-render objects (that only exist to bounce light and simulate the real world environment) end up rendering. How can I filter ray bounces to only the ones bounced by certain objects? for example,

[image: Visual representation]

How can I make only the blue and green rays (Bouncing off Suzanne) render and make sure that the yellow ray DOESN'T?

for context, I need a specular object to reflect onto it's surroundings but the `glossy indirect` pass picks up the bounced light from the rebuilt scene which messes up my compositing.

Comment: Maybe Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility is what you are looking for?

Comment: @ViplavPrakash That doesn't work, because if I do that, the plane will no longer affect the object. In the image, it would cancel yellow, green and blue which I don't want.